# Powershell Script to create a new Group from a list of OU and then add User Objects from the OU to the group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have created a script that will query AD for OU's, output them to a file, then will create a group from the file with a small modification to the new group name. That part works here is the code:

```
## Load Quest ActiveRoles ADManagement PSSnapin if not already loaded
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name "Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) { 
  Add-PsSnapin "Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement" } 

cd \
cls

$Type = "Security"
$Scope = "Global"
$Domain = "abc.org"


## Get Organizational Units

Get-QADObject -Type OrganizationalUnit `
| Select-Object Name, Path, DN, CanonicalName ` | Export-Csv -Path "c:\scripts\test\ou.csv" -NoTypeInformation

## Create Security Groups from Organizational Units
$Pre = "123abc"
$ou  = "ou=123abc,ou=Groups,ou=User Accounts,dc=abc,dc=org"
Import-Csv -Path "c:\scripts\test\ou.csv" | foreach {New-QADGroup -name ($Pre+$_.name) -parent $ou -sam ($Pre+$_.name)}
```

The problem I am having an issue is with this. How do I get the user objects from each of the OU's and place them in a separate csv files. I have this little bit of code that works for a single OU.

```
$OuDomain = "OU=123abc,OU=Users,OU=User Accounts,DC=abc,DC=org"
Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 0 -searchRoot $OuDomain `
| Select-Object name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName `
| Export-Csv -Path "c:\scripts\test\123abc.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

after that I should be able to add the users to the new groups.

Answer (score 0):

**First** if you are usingPowerShell V2.0 you can use Microsoft ActiveDirectory module on W2K8R2.

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity MonGroupe -Member massin
```

**Second** once you've got the users from the OU, you will be interested in the `distinguishedName` attribute. You just have to assign the distinguishedName of each user to the attribute `member` of your new group.

I have not Quest ADManagement PSSnapin installed, so here is a simple ADSI example :

```
# Starting OU
$MonOU = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://192.168.234.200:389/ou=Monou,dc=dom,dc=fr","administrateur@dom.fr","admin")

# Group creation
$MonGroupe = $Monou.Create("Group", "cn=MonGroupe")
$ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP = 0x00000002
$ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED = 0x80000000
$groupeType = $ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED -bor $ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP

$MonGroupe.put("groupType",$groupeType) 
$MonGroupe.setinfo()

# Add a user to the group
$MonGroupe.add('LDAP://cn=Marc Assin,ou=Monou,dc=dom,dc=fr')
$MonGroupe.setinfo()

# List members of a group
$UnGroupe = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://192.168.234.200:389/cn=Mongroupe,ou=Monou,dc=dom,dc=fr","administrateur@dom.fr","admin")
$Membres = $UnGroupe.Member
$Membres
```